# Usage of Middle English "fel it hap"

Tags: phrase-usage, middle-english

The [OED entry for *happen*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/happen#etymonline_v_1456) notes the following:

> In Middle English *fel it hap* meant "it happened."

A search for the phrase reveals this OED entry and nothing else relevant. It is not clear how one would use this phrase in a conversational context. For example, could it be used in a sentence like the following?

> Fel it hap **that** the man did dege.

i.e.:

> It happened **that** the man died.

Or, was it used as an exclamation?

> The man did dege! Fel it hap!

**All "Middle-English-y" example sentences here are of my own making, and I know nothing about Middle English.*

**How was this phrase used? Can you provide any notable examples from medieval works?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess 'fel it hap' was a nonce *nonce* expression. Almost all the sources I checked give only one example (the one I've posted as an answer). I didn't find any other example.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example seems correct to me. Here's a quote from ME compendium:

> Þan **fel it hap** þat þei founde ful sone a grete bor.
>
> [[Middle English Compendium]](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED19945)

Another example in poetry:

> In þat faire forest feiþely for to telle;
>
> Wiþ alle his menskful meyné, 
> þat moche was & nobul;
>
> **Þan fel it hap**, þat þei founde ful sone a grete bor,
>
> & huntyng wiþ hound & horn harde alle sewede;
>
>  [[Wikisource]](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:The_Sources_of_Standard_English.djvu/234)

> Then fel it hap that thei founde ful sone a grete bor
>
>  [[Ancient Metrical Tales - Google Books]](https://books.google.com/books?id=HDgJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22fel%20it%20hap%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw8OvyqMfrAhX06OAKHQ2lCMsQ6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fel%20it%20hap%22&f=false)

Comment: Why do you have the same example twice (#1 and #3)?

Comment: @Laurel, This is the only example I could find. And it's *thrice* not twice. :P